# Trouble with reading JSON files in C++

Tags: c++, json

I want to read data from a JSON file in C++, and I know there are several different libraries I can use. The problem is, I need to send the code to someone once it's done, and I need this person to be able to run the code in their IDE without installing anything.

All the JSON libraries in C++ require installation, so I don't know how to proceed. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: The problem then is for the other person. Either they install a C++ library or other tool that supports it natively like javascript or python. In the end JSON is just a data format.

Comment: I guess another option is to send the library used with your code.

Comment: You could use a header only library like [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and add the code to your own repo. This won't require any installation process for the person you send the code to.

Comment: There are header only json libraries. no need any installation.

Comment: Write your own JSON parser.